# How do I generate a random range of numbers within another range?

Tags: php, random

Apologies for the confusing title, I couldn't phrase it much differently.

I want to be able to generate a random range of x number(s) within the number 10000.

Such as 200-500 (201, 202, 203... ...499) or 9700 to 10000.

I also want the function to be easily changed so it will be a range of x-amount numbers. The above was a range of 200, x = 200... I would like to be able to easily change that.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by a "random range"?  Can you give a concrete example?

Comment: I felt that I did.

I want to generate a sequence of y numbers within the number 10,000 such as 200 through 500, 100 through 400, 654 through 954...

Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Makes use of [range()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php):

```
$min = 1;
$max = 10000;

$nb = 300;

// in this example, $start can be from 1 to 9701
$start = mt_rand($min, $max - $nb + 1);

// in this example, $result can be from [1;300] to [9701;10000]
$result = range($start, $start + $nb - 1);
```

Comment: Thank you, that's great - but for some reason it only gives me 299 numbers, would $nb = 301 give me 300 exactly?

Comment: I've just double-checked my code, it is right. If count($result) != 300 you should have done a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Try [mt_rand()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php)

```
echo mt_rand(0, 10000);
```